# Determine the given relation is Equivalence Relation or not.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

$R_{1} \oplus R_{2}$

I know that $R_{1} \oplus R_{2} = R_{1} \cup R_{2} - R_{1} \cap R_{2}$, and $R_{1} \cup R_{2}$ is not necessarily an equivalence relation but $R_{1} \cap R_{2}$ is always an equivalence relation, when we subtract what we will get? 
[For example consider this, what will be the graph of $R_{1} \oplus R_{2}$?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3aRE.jpg)

Comment: Hint: It can't be reflexive.

Comment: If it can't be reflexive then it's not an equivalence relation. But why so?

Comment: ok got it. Thanks for the hint.